# Trying to download a file, losing return value type in responseHandler in queryFn when using baseQueryWithReauth

Tags: typescript, redux, rtk-query

I am trying to download a file using a mutation endpoint which wraps a queryFn. The code for the mutation looks like:

```
downloadTournamentTRF: builder.mutation<{filename: string}, {id: Tournament["id"]}>({
    queryFn: async ({id}, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        return baseQuery({
            url: `/tournament/trf/${id}`,
            responseHandler: async (response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    const filename = await saveResponseUsingHiddenElement(response);
                    return {data: {filename}};
                } else {
                    return {error: {status: response.status, message: response.statusText}};
                }
            },
            cache: "no-cache"
        });
    }
}),
```

This generates an error on the `queryFn` type:

```
TS2322: Type '({ id }: { id: number; }, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: string | FetchArgs) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>>) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(arg: { id: number; }, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: string | FetchArgs) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>>) => MaybePromise<...>’.
   Type 'Promise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>>' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<{ filename: string; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>>’.
     Type 'Promise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<QueryReturnValue<{ filename: string; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>>’.
       Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
         Type '<TResult1 = QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = QueryReturnValue<{ filename: string; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: QueryReturnValue<{ filename: string; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 mo...’.
           Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
             Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
               Type 'QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<{ filename: string; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>’.
                 Type '{ error?: undefined; data: unknown; meta?: {} | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<{ filename: string; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>’.
                   Type '{ error?: undefined; data: unknown; meta?: {} | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ error?: undefined; data: { filename: string; }; meta?: unknown; }’.
                     Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
                       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ filename: string; }’.
```

In our baseQuery, we are using a `baseQueryWithReauth` function based on the code from from documentation [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery). Our code is virtually unchanged and looks like:

```
const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs,
    unknown,
    FetchBaseQueryError> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    [...]
};
```

The issue appears to be that the second type argument to the `BaseQueryFn` generic is set to `unknown` and that seems to squelch the return type causing the error.

Is there a way I can change that type definition to preserve the return type and clean up the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`baseQuery` will always return `unknown` - it gets data from the server and there is no way of knowing what that is.
If you as a programmer know better here, you can always do a `as Something` - or you write a custom assertion function or use something like `zod` to parse & verify the return type.

---

On second look, you were just overdoing it - `queryFn` needs to return an object in the shape `{data}` or `{error}`, but `transformResponse` doesn't need to. And it doesn't look like you need `queryFn` here at all.

This should do:

```
export const chessMasterApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'chessMasterApi',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  tagTypes: ['Audit'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    downloadTournamentTRF: builder.mutation<
      { filename: string },
      { id: Tournament['id'] }
    >({
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        url: `/tournament/trf/${id}`,
        responseHandler: async (response) => {
          return await saveResponseUsingHiddenElement(response);
        },
        cache: 'no-cache',
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: I’m pretty confident I know better here but I can’t work out where to put the `as something` to resolve the type error that doesn’t seem to cause a cascade of other errors

Comment: `{data: {filename as something}}`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and any number of different options and I just cannot get typescript to be happy with what I put in there. I've put up a cut down version of the project here if you'd like to have a look at it https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-utrdi3?file=chessmasterApi.ts

Answer (score 0):

That's really great and works nicely -- thanks for your help!

The one change I had to make was to get it to handle errors correctly:

```
export const chessMasterApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'chessMasterApi',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  tagTypes: ['Audit'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    downloadTournamentTRF: builder.mutation<
      { filename: string },
      { id: Tournament['id'] }
    >({
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        url: `/tournament/trf/${id}`,
        responseHandler: async (response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return await saveResponseUsingHiddenElement(response);
          } else {
            return {message: response.statusText};
        },
        cache: 'no-cache',
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```